# Refresh aggregation results in ag-grid

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I have an `ag-grid` with rows grouped by one column and I want to show in the same line (group header) a value taken from first row in the group.

I found out that I can use aggregation for this, but I also want to dynamically update rows and group header in accordance with this.

To update aggregation and group header I tried to use `gridApi.recomputeAggregates()`, but this function refreshes the whole table on every call. Is it a right behavior? How can I avoid it?

Comment: You only want to refresh the grouped rows, right ? Did you tried `refreshRows(rowNodes)` ? You can find the doc here: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-refresh/#gsc.tab=0

Comment: I'd like to update group header which show some aggregated result. I found out only one case - when I'm updating row to find a row's parent (group header), change aggregated result and update this header row via `refreshRows(headerRows)`. But it looks awful and requires too much manual work from my perspective.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add valuePerser to your column defenition and parse the value as number.

```
colDef.valuePerser = 'Number(newValue)';
```

Check out the documentation about [Change Detection](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-change-detection/?framework=react#example-change-detection-groups).